# Getting error when i'm starting my own service "Job for adtech.service failed."

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I wrote a service for wrap a jar file run as a service.. This is the service file.

```
#!/bin/sh-
SERVICE_NAME=adtech-service
PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/ADTECH/dist/ADTECH.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/adtech-service-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

after i tried to start my service executing by following code.

```
sudo service adtech start
```

But it's gives following error

```
Job for adtech.service failed. See "systemctl status adtech.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@eyepax-staging:/# systemctl status adtech.service
● adtech.service - (null)
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/adtech)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-12-04 03:52:19 UTC; 12s ago
      Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 10913 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/adtech start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 04 03:52:19 eyepax-staging systemd[1]: Starting (null)...
Dec 04 03:52:19 eyepax-staging systemd[1]: adtech.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 04 03:52:19 eyepax-staging systemd[1]: Failed to start (null).
Dec 04 03:52:19 eyepax-staging systemd[1]: Unit adtech.service entered failed state.
Dec 04 03:52:19 eyepax-staging systemd[1]: adtech.service failed.
```

any one can tell me what wrong with my code ?

Comment: Have you tried running the jar file without the wrapper? Have you tried running as root?

Comment: @PbxMan yes. my jar file is running no errors without wrapper and also run as a root. :(

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the nohup command. Have you running the jar file with nohup from console. Also double check the "2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &" from the wrapper.

Comment: @PbxMan yeah its working with nohup from console. I don't know what to do. i didn't do any thing for wrapper beside changing PATH_TO_JAR and PID_PATH_NAME.

Comment: Have you tried removing the /dev/null part? Why don't you try a remote debug to see what is going on in your jar file? What's your 203 error code?

Comment: yp i remove all thing and 

`#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=adtech-service
PATH_TO_JAR=/opt/ADTECH/dist/ADTECH.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/adtech-service-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac`

added only this. but giving above error